# Merging two css-files with node-sass

Tags: bulma, node-sass

I am using bulma as a CSS framework for my homepage. However one plugin is using bootstrap and bootstrap-editable, so I am looking for a solution, how I can add the bootstrap.css and bootstrap-editable.css without destroying my layout.

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- header designed with bulma -->
<!-- left column menu designed with bulma -->
<div class="column>
<table class="table-responsive">
...
</table>
</div>
<!- footer designed with bulma -->
</body>
</html>
```

Im creating my css files by node-sass using **npm run css-build**, as described [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/).

```
@charset "utf-8";

// Set your brand colors
$blue:  hsl(217, 71%, 53%);

// Update Bulma's global variables
$primary: $blue;


// Import only what you need from Bulma
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/components/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/form/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/grid/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/helpers/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/_all.sass";

@import "my.scss";
```

Now I am looking for a solution, how I can apply the two css-files from bootstrap just for the .table-responsive - Class.

I already tried something like that, but this is not working:

```
.table-responsive {
    @import "bootstrap.min.css";
    @import "bootstrap-editable.css";
}
```

In the generated css-file, there is a class table-responsive, but the class is empty:

```
.table-responsive { }
```

Can you tell me, how I can import a css file just for one class?

Thomas

My package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "css-build": "node-sass --omit-source-map-url sass/mystyles.scss css/mystyles.css",
  "css-watch": "npm run css-build -- --watch",
  "start": "npm run css-watch"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing inside the `.table-responsive` declaration you could try to import just the required SCSS and the table component from Bootstrap at the "top-level" like you do with Bulma.

Have a look at the changes I've made to your SCSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

// Set your brand colors
$blue:  hsl(217, 71%, 53%);

// Update Bulma's global variables
$primary: $blue;

// Import only what you need from Bulma
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/components/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/form/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/grid/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/helpers/_all.sass";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/_all.sass";

// Add required Bootstrap SCSS

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Add the tables component

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "bootstrap-editable.css";

@import "my.scss";
```

All you have to do is make sure that you have Bootstrap installed through NPM. You should also double check that you don't have any conflicting class names or styles.

I've made [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/Klooven/39e0143d63b5f4efca34c994e94770fa#file-_input-scss) where I've listed all of the different components you can import from Bootstrap. If you need other components you can just import them as you need.